# Obtaining a Unique Device ID

Tags: ios

I am needing to uniquely ID devices that connect to our service. I have found the following

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/DeviceInfoPlugin

I am reading that Apple will reject your app if you try to get device info. Will this work or what is another way to uniquely ID a device?

Comment: The project you linked to uses `identifierForVendor` on iOS so you won't be rejected if you use it. You can also add your own UUID to the keychain. The Device Check framework may also help depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Can the UUID be stored on the phone even if your app is uninstalled?

Comment: Yes, data persists in the keychain across installs but not if the phone is erased